# Why doesn't the Gemara learn kiddushei kesef from Eliezer initiating kiddushei kesef as a shaliach for Yitzchak?

Tags: parashat-chaye-sara, maseches-kiddushin, kiddushin-eirusin, eliezer

I'm learning Kiddushin this year and while I haven't yet gotten to the Sugya which delves deeply into the issue of how to derive kiddushei kesef from the *gzera shava "Kicha Kicha"* I know that *kiddushei kesef* is learned out from Avraham purchasing *Ma'arat HaMachpela* from Efron (Kiddushin 2a). From the fact we know that land can be bought with *kesef* we use a rule of parsimony to assume that the land Avraham actually was *makne* the *me'ara* with *kesef*.

Now as I was learning the parsha this morning and came to the point where Eliezer is *mikadesh* Rivka as a *shaliach* for Yitzchak it dawned upon me that this would have been a perfect source to learn out Kiddushei kesef.

> וַיְהִ֗י כַּאֲשֶׁ֨ר כִּלּ֤וּ הַגְּמַלִּים֙ לִשְׁתּ֔וֹת **וַיִּקַּ֤ח הָאִישׁ֙ נֶ֣זֶם זָהָ֔ב בֶּ֖קַע מִשְׁקָל֑וֹ וּשְׁנֵ֤י צְמִידִים֙** עַל־יָדֶ֔יהָ עֲשָׂרָ֥ה זָהָ֖ב מִשְׁקָלָֽם׃
>
> (Breishit 24:22)

I am aware it is debated which one of Eliezer's two gifts actually constituted the Kiddushin.
However I'm surprised this pasuk isn't even brought up in the Gemara.

Comment: Why do you think that the verse is referring to Kiddushin?

Comment: סיבלונות? Perhaps

Comment: She was a kitana, kidduchin was with her father, see seforno beraishis 24.61 http://www.sefaria.org/Sforno_on_Genesis.24.61.1 ketubot 48b . there was not kedushin before matan Torah.- what with it teach you by her? by the field it teaches you more rules but by rivka it will just be kidduchin not teaching you any rules,

Comment: "I am aware it is debated which one of Eliezer's two gifts actually constituted the Kiddushin" Source please

Comment: That verse is before he even proposes the marriage, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually not clear that Eliezer was *mikadesh* Rivka at all, see Moshav Zekeinim and Pirkei Drebbi Eliezer chapter 16.

Also, even if he was *mikadesh* her, what reason would there be to assume that *kiddushin* post-Sinai works the same way? The *gzera shava* you mentioned is superior because it links Avraham's purchase to the current commandment of *kiddushin* in Ki Teitzei 24:1.

Comment: Can y explain what you have found in Pirke Derabbi Eliezer.?

Comment: @kouty My understanding is it's implied there that it was Nissuin that Eliezer performed, rather than kiddushin.  (The first source says explicitly that it was not kiddushin, because Yitzchok would have been careful to be mikadesh her himself in accordance with the ideas  expressed in Kiddushin 41a)